# How do you programmatically enumerate all image sets in an iOS asset catalog?

Tags: ios7, assets

I'd like to list all the image sets available in an application's asset catalog with the iOS 7.x SDK. I think I may be able to iterate through the folders in the app bundle, but I don't see another way. Is there a better way?

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out myself as well. I'll let you know if I find the optimal way.

Comment: Share some code to show how you're currently doing it, please...

Comment: Well, this was two years ago, and the problem went away. I never did anything because I never knew the best way. I was working on a sample app for an open-source control. I was working with a designer who might have contributed a lot of images to use with the control. I wanted to give the user the ability to choose from any image in the asset catalog without having to maintain a separate list. As it turned out, there were three, so I forgot about this. At this point I'd probably use NSBundle or NSFileManager to try to enumerate image files in the bundle or something. That's all I can say.